# Durandal: Include splat inside compose binding

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, knockout-2.0, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I have this **splat route** configured inside shell.js

```
 router.map([
   { route: 'projects*modal', title: 'Projects', moduleId: 'views/projects', nav: true },
]).buildNavigationModel();
```

and this is how I try to compose the view with some splat parameter **inside custom modal view**

```
<div data-bind="compose: 'views/projects/thisIsOptionalSplatParameter'"></div>
```

**This doesn't work**. It only work when I update it directly on addressbar.

So, how can I include some parameters inside **compose binding** to the route ?

I need to let the page know if I used it inside a modal or not.. So I need to pass something like this:

```
http://localhost/#projects/modalTrue
```

and retrieve it using **activate function** inside the **projects page**:

```
var isInModal;

activate: function(params)
{
   if (typeof params !== 'undefined' && params !== null && params.replace('/', '') === 'modalTrue')
        isInModal = true;
    else
        isInModal = false;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried leveraging the [activationData attribute](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html#activation-data) for the compose binding?
Your outer view may catch the route params, store it in an observable, which again is provided via activationData to the composed view.